# how i can get individual consumer id from a grouped data?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
DGroup=df.groupby(['Conmer id','Purchase date']).count()
```

Conmer id  Purchase date            A          B         C      D

2397     2017-07-29 19:05:24        1         1          1     1

4107     2016-03-31 19:06:54        1         0          0     1

```
         2016-04-01 05:41:55        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-02 06:18:16        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-03 05:28:02        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-04 05:47:08        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-05 05:15:10        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-09 05:40:06        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-10 05:02:34        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-11 05:06:18        1         0          0     1
```

....
234       2016-03-31 11:06:54        1         0          0     1

```
         2016-04-01 05:41:55        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-02 16:18:16        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-03 15:28:02        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-04 15:47:08        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-05 15:15:10        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-09 15:40:06        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-10 11:02:34        1         0          0     1  

         2016-04-11 13:06:18        1         0          0     1
```

2634     2015-08-16 18:26:46   1      1     1       1            0

`2017-11-30 11:42:50   1      1     1       1            0   

         2017-12-01 06:14:47   1      1     1       1            0   

         2017-12-02 06:09:43   1      1     1       1            0`

....

now how i can get individual consumer id from this grouped data with cunsumer id and date (with the entire row) in to another variable for plotting and analysing?

Comment: can you show us expected output and your efforts?

Comment: Sorry, you need `.xs`, so changed dupe.

Comment: DGroup is not what i am looking, i wanted to take out consumer 4107 all values which i got after grouping as above to another variable. currently all consumers values are listed , but i need to take out single consumer 2016,2017 data from the above format to a variable.

Comment: 'for Conmer id, group in grouped:
   group.to_csv('/Users/path'+str(Conmer id)'.csv'
    print Conmer id
    print group'  above code is  used to save and print each grouped data separately and